# Selecting particulars in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a table in which I have different particulars and different quantities for same ID, now I want quantities of each particular separately for that same particular ID to be printed.

```
$mq="SELECT count( particulars ) AS 'n' FROM delivery_challan WHERE job_order_id =".$_GET['jo'];
$ha=mysqli_query($link,$mq);


   $haha=mysqli_fetch_object($ha);
   $n=$haha->n;
   echo $n;
   for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
   {
        $nq="SELECT qty FROM `delivery_challan` WHERE job_order_id=".$_GET['jo'];

        $r=mysqli_query($link,$nq);

    //$i=1;
        $rs=mysqli_fetch_object($r);
        $qty=$rs->qty;
}
```

This is how I am trying to fetch the respective quantity in $qty variable. This variable is used below :

```
 <td><input name="invqty[]" type="text" onchange="SetDefault(<?php echo $cnt; ?>, $(this).val());" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();" class="form-control1" id="invqty<?php echo $cnt; ?>" size="5" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>"></td>
```

For example :

In my table 'delivery_challan' I have 3 particulars x, y & z with 3 different quantities 10,20 & 30 respectively. Now in the above mentioned  I want all the three quantities to be printed. The  is being printed 3 times correctly, but in all 3 's only 10 is printed where as 10 then 20 and in 3rd, 30 must be printed.
But only the first value is being printed.

I am not able find a solution. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: please show desired output and your output and your code  @rushi kulkarni

Comment: Show some input and what is expected

Comment: without seeing your data structure the question is unanswerable. Also if you have tried some code that didn't work, please post it here and explain what went wrong. People like to know that you have made some effort to solve it yourself before asking others to volunteer their time to help you.

Comment: I have edited my code. Please see above. @Pritamkumar

Comment: Please see above. @AnkurGarg

Comment: Please see above. @ADyson

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: As for your question, you're going about this completely the wrong way. You don't even need two queries for this. A basic mysqli tutorial would show you what to do, but I'll post an example answer to help you.

Comment: @ADyson I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. You don't need to fetch a count of the results first, instead you can just loop through the result set from the main query until you reach the end. This example uses prepared statements and parameters to protect your database from injection attacks:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT qty FROM `delivery_challan` WHERE job_order_id= ?")) 
{
  //bind the job order parameter
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_GET['jo']);

  //execute the query
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

  //bind the columns in the result to variables for use in the next part
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $qty);

  //loop through all the rows returned, and print the output
  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
     echo '<td><input name="invqty[]" type="text" onchange="SetDefault(<?php echo $cnt; ?>, $(this).val());" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();" class="form-control1" id="invqty<?php echo $cnt; ?>" size="5" value="'.$qty.'"></td>';
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
else
{
  echo "ERROR - failed to prepare SQL statement";
  //here you should log the result of running mysqli_error() to your application's error log. Don't show it to the user.
}
```

You can see more examples here, for instance: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Thanks man, it did work, There are some row/column issues, but the output is correct. I will solve those minor issues, thanks again. @ADyson

Answer (score 1):

```
select item_tbl.id as item_id, user.id as user_id, order.id as order_id
```

You can get the IDs in this way.

Answer (score 0):

try this. No need to make query for count.

```
$mq="SELECT qty FROM delivery_challan WHERE job_order_id =".$_GET['jo'];
$ha=mysqli_query($link,$mq);
while($haha=mysqli_fetch_object($ha))
 {
   $qty=$haha->qty;
   echo $qty;
 }
```

Use this $qty variable, the way you need.